# Where did my questions and answers go in Meta?

Tags: support

My profile in Meta says, "You have not asked any questions" and "You have not answered any questions".  I know that's not the case.  Were some old posts recently scrubbed or something?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/161837/wefx

Comment: Maybe you're looking for MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/161837/wefx

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, I missed the memo.  Apparently, things got moved from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/123456/username to https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/123456/username .